Did Nazi Germany have the Highest Per-Capita Rate of Capital Punishment?
I am not talking about extra-judicial murders but actual judicial sentencing to Germany's own citizens.
I read in the Wikipedia article that 40K executions occurred during the nazi period which I think is very much higher than any modern state.
The period I am interested in is 20th century to present. I am aware that at one time, for example, England had capital punishment for petty theft and this lasted until the early 1800s. I assume this meant a very high number of judicial executions.

Compared with the USSR and (a bit later) China, pretty mild.

@Jos - The last year I could get data for China it said "1000+". That's a lot, and menacingly vague, but still a far cry from 40k, and with several times the population. However, if you added numbers for the Cultural Revolution...

This paper seems to say 16500 Third Reich total (just googled, not read the paper). ISTR something like 20K+ executions in the military, so the 40K may include those.

"The exact number of executions [in Russia in the 1930s] is debated, with archival research suggesting it to be between 700,000 and 800,000, whereas an official report to Nikita Khrushchev from 1954 cites 642,980 death penalty sentences." (wiki)

"the estimated number of executions [in China] has declined steadily in the twenty-first century, from 12,000 each year to 2,400." (wiki)

Capital punishment -- including court-martial? Per capita -- what do you consider "capita"? Germany's borders of 1937? Germany and Austria? Occupied territories? Same for any country you would compare this against, at least during the war.

This WP article, quoting Im Namen des Deutschen Volkes - Justiz im Nationalsozialismus. Cologne 1989, ISBN 3-8046-8731-8, p. 206, states 25,000+ death penalties in Germany by court-martial (Kriegsgericht) and drumhead court-martial (Standgericht), plus 16,000+ death penalties by civil courts.

@T.E.D. Exactly my point. The same goes for the USSR. Stalin's purges were most of the time legal.

The problem here is trying to sort Nazi actions by modern categories of "legal" and "extralegal." Counting a supposed defeatist who was hanged by a lampost during the last days of the war as "legal" and a foreign worker who was beaten to death for being too slow as "extralegal" is giving too much credit to the Nazi legal system. The Nazi legal system had no rule of law.

@o.m. The 16.5k do not include either of those.

@o.m. I'd find interest in comparing the number of individual death warrants issued by a putatively judicial process vs the number of actual lives ended by state sanctioned violence, in a ”L'hypocrisie est un hommage..." sense. But that's useful in a monograph or a thesis, problematic in a spreadsheet or SE answer.

Frame Challenge: This is one of those questions where an explicit answer tends to reveal more about the answerer than the subject itself. "Capital punishment" can include a broad spectrum of actions and circumstances that make it very easy to end up comparing very different phenomena grouped under the same name, or conversely to exclude a particular nation's actions for arguably arbitrary distinctions.
Compare for instance a fairly stable and established regime with a long history of executing thieves and murderers to a new revolutionary regime disposing of its opponents. Both might be conducting executions managed judicially under color of law, but putting them on the same spreadsheet seems like a misleading comparison at best. So if we decide to make those separate categories, where do we put a fairly stable and established regime that also executes dissidents and blasphemers?
How are we deciding what the boundaries of "fairly stable and established" are? Do we only count judicial declarations of execution, or also judicial sentencing to circumstances (labor camps, etc) which will obviously and intentionally result in a high probability of death in short order? How about executive and legislative decisions that deliberately create famines and relocations that produce mass deaths? How about executive and legislative decisions that (arguably) accidentally produce the same results?
I'm not saying there is no meaning to be gleaned by making these analyses, but there's an unavoidable degree of editorial input in choosing which deaths "count". This does not inherently make make any particular comparison wrong, just tricky and prone to misuse (intentional or otherwise). The best we can do is try to be very clear about why we're choosing the definitions and metrics we are, apply them as consistently as possible, not draw too many conclusions on numbers alone, and be very careful about using such necessarily subjective results to support another narrative.
